# Replacing text with Open XML SDK

Tags: c#, docx, openxml-sdk

I have a small program which generates some documents by taking user input and writing replacing a string in a template. I have some variables, like dates and the name of the person creating the document. But I have two variables, latitude and longitude, that I can't get to be replaced in the generated document. In the document template I use, all of the fields that need to be replaced have this format: {field}. So replacing a name looks like: {name}. All of the half-dozen variables I have work except for the longitude and latitude. These numbers are grid coordinates, so they are written like `12.3456,-98.7654`. I define these as a string (along with all of my other variables). I think my regex is incorrect/broken.

For example, the longitude functions look like this:

```
 Console.WriteLine("Enter Longitude");
 longitude = Console.ReadLine();
 Console.WriteLine($"Longitude: {longitude}");
```

And the regex that replaces text in the document looks like this:

```
Regex regexLongitude = new Regex("{longitude}");
docText = regexLongitude.Replace(docText, longitude);
```

The latitude function is identical, just replace `longitude` with `latitude`. In fact, all of my variables are defined and used in these same functions.

This issue is consistent and reproducible. I have tried renaming the variable, redefining the variable as a float (which I don't think I did correctly anyway), even just using a random string of numbers without a decimal point. Even if I use text, like `abc` for the coordinates, they aren't replaced. Something in the regex just skips over this. I have been doing research for the past few days and am now at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is not correct. I'm not sure if i understood what you want to do but i think that all you need is replace an word to another, right? All you need to is

try this :
 `var text = "{field} bla bla bla bla {field}";
        var coordinate = "123.002-123-000";
        var replacedText = text.Replace("{field} ",coordinate);
        Console.WriteLine(replacedText);`

your answer will be:
`123.002-123-000 bla bla bla bla 123.002-123-000`

Comment: Does this work with a docx file? That is the file I am writing to. I am taking user input and replacing all occurrences of the value in the docx file.

Comment: Well, you'll need to read all lines and use the string replace. Try to read the file and send  the output to us

Comment: This didn't work. Is there any reason why I can't use the same regex functions for latitude and longitude as I do for my other variables, like name and date?